# '{{ ds }}' does not increment

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

for some reason the macro '{{ ds }}' does not increment
the execution date does increment but it does not apply to the macro for some reason
i tried a clean new dag id and still does not help. any idea?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GVNV.png)

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/datarona/')
from datarona_query import queries

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date':  datetime(2020,4,15),
}

dag = DAG('datarona_tester', description='calculate datarona tables',
          schedule_interval='30 0 * * *',
          default_args=args,
          max_active_runs=1
                 )

#check_cross_dag_dependency = ExternalTaskSensor(task_id='wait_wordpress_succededs',external_dag_id='wordpress',external_task_id='all_tasks_succeded',dag=dag)
next_ds_converter = lambda x,y: (y + timedelta(days=1)) if x==y else (y)
first_operator = PostgresOperator(task_id='opportunities',dag=dag,sql=queries['oppportunities'].replace('next_dt',next_ds_converter('{{ ds }}','{{ next_ds }}')).replace('current_dt','{{ ds }}'),postgres_conn_id='redshift_default')


first_operator
#check_cross_dag_dependency >> first_operator
```

Answer (score 0):

a few remarks:

- ExternalTaskSensor needs to have either execution_delta or execution_date_fn specified, otherwise it won't refer to a specific task run. [Mentioned in the documentation here](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/)
- You set start date to 2020-04-15 and the schedule to daily 00:30. In your screenshot you marked the 3rd run, and this execution date matches exactly the configuration (first run on 04-15, second run on 04-16 and 3rd run on 04-17)
- ds and next_ds can't be similar: next_ds = ds + schedule, see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref.html)